# PHP Codeigniter Error: mb_internal_encoding()

Tags: php, codeigniter, helper

I recently installed XAMPP for Linux 5.6.3-0 on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. I copied a project I was working on before in to the 'htdocs' folder. I have several CI applications using one instance Codeigniter withing this project.

My directory structure:

[image: http://jmauricedesigns.com/assets/img/to_delete/QJrt4.png]

Here is the error:

[image: http://jmauricedesigns.com/assets/img/to_delete/QJrt5.png]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't know Codigniter, but for me it seems, somewhere you have the line `mb_internal_encoding($somevar)`. What is the `var_dump` of `$somevar`? If it is `string(0)` where that var get his value?

Comment: Start searching in `%CodigniterDir%/core/Utf8.php`